# Database directory disappeared

Tags: mysql, innodb

One of my clients complained that his database disappeared without any reason. I guess he must have dropped the database by mistake. But I just want to make sure that this can not happen automatically. The ibdata and iblog files are there but the directory (for e.g. company) is missing.

Answer (score 0):

It does not happen automatically. If you log the SQL queries (bin log, for example) you can search if there was a "drop database" query.

Answer (score 0):

if you properly manage your database permissions then this should not be possible, only give drop DB access to root or to your superuser.